# Object eligible for the garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Given:

```
interface Animal {
    void makeNoise();
}

class Horse implements Animal {
    Long weight = 1200L;

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("whinny");
    }
}

public class Icelandic extends Horse {
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("vinny");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Icelandic i1 = new Icelandic();
        Icelandic i2 = new Icelandic();
        Icelandic i3 = new Icelandic();
        i3 = i1;
        i1 = i2;
        i2 = null;
        i3 = i1;
        System.out.println("end of program");
    }
}
```

how many objects are eligible for the garbage collector at the last statement (ie:where printing end of program)?
The answer is 4 but i did not understand How they are 4 and there are at max 3 objects?

Comment: So is this homework or an interview question?

Comment: @TC1 It's from the OCPJP mock example. It's been answers many times already.

Comment: I don't feel like mentally stepping through this silliness, but are you accounting for the `Long weight`? It generates an object (via autoboxing) whose lifecycle is tied to the `Animal`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, well spotted. :)

Comment: @AlpeshGediya I remember wondering; were all Icelandics horses!? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking at this correctly.  Not all "Icelandic" objects are eligible for garbage collection at this line.  And each "Icelandic" object has another object, specifically a Long, which is also eligible for garbage collection, when it's containing "Icelandic" object goes out of scope and/or no longer has a live reference to it.

In this example, the original i2 object, and the Long that "belongs to it" is not eligible for garbage collection until after System.log line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "at" you mean "exactly before" (as we do with breakpoints).

If you follow the **language** specification strictly, by my count there are 2 `Icelandic` objects eligible for garbage collection, each containing one `Long`, so **4 objects eligible** in total.

In practical **implementations**, however, with all the optimizations that they typically use, lots of other numbers are possible. For example:

- The JIT might tell the GC that `args` is never used below that point, so it's eligible  before it "officially" goes out of scope (plus 1, then). But with that optimization in place, so would the remaining `Icelandic` object and its `Long` (so plus 2 more).
- A JVM may choose to intern `Long` objects at an arbitrary range, thus interned values will not be garbage collected (minus 2 or 3, in this case, depending on whether the previous optimization is in place).
- Any number of other optimizations may be occurring that change the value.

You really cannot know in practice, unless you have a very thorough understanding of the implementation of the executing runtime.

Comment: Or, you could take this for what it is: "A simple interview question dealing with basic inheritance/garbage collecting concepts."  Answer 4, and leave the advanced optimization discussion for the face to face part of the interview :)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is the question does not have an answer.

The `String[]` containing the command-line arguments might become eligible for GC at the end of the call.  The `Long` value might or might not be in a cache internal to `Long.valueOf`.

Assigning to a local variable which is not subsequently read is not guaranteed to have an effect on GC because assignments may be optimized and variables may be reused due to [liveness analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis), and this may change after JIT compilation of code.